# How I can Add Text inside Frame TabbedRenderer in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am customizing Badge in TabbedPage. I have now added the red dot from inheriting UIView. However how can I Add Text inside that Frame. Xamarin iOS

**MyTabbedPageRenderer.cs**

```
public static class TabbarExtensions
{
    readonly static int tabBarItemTag = 9999;
    public static void addItemBadge(this UITabBar tabbar, int index)
    {
        if (tabbar.Items != null && tabbar.Items.Length == 0) return;

        if (index >= tabbar.Items.Length) return;

        removeItemBadge(tabbar, index);

        var badgeView = new UIView();
        badgeView.Tag = tabBarItemTag + index;
        badgeView.Layer.CornerRadius = 7;
        badgeView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

        var tabFrame = tabbar.Frame;
        var percentX = (index + 0.56) / tabbar.Items.Length;
        var x = percentX * tabFrame.Width;
        var y = tabFrame.Height * 0.05;
        badgeView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(x, y, 13, 13);
        tabbar.AddSubview(badgeView);


        //var badgeView = new UILabel();
        //badgeView.Tag = tabBarItemTag + index;            
        //badgeView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        //var tabFrame = tabbar.Frame;
        //var percentX = (index + 0.56) / tabbar.Items.Length;
        //var x = percentX * tabFrame.Width;
        //var y = tabFrame.Height * 0.05;
        //badgeView.Text = "1";
        //badgeView.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        //badgeView.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        //badgeView.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(10);
        //tabbar.AddSubview(badgeView);
    }

    public static bool removeItemBadge(this UITabBar tabbar, int index)
    {
        foreach (var subView in tabbar.Subviews)
        {
            if (subView.Tag == tabBarItemTag + index)
            {
                subView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "Add", (obj, index) => {
        TabBar.addItemBadge(index);
    });
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, int>(this, "Remove", (obj, index) => {
        TabBar.removeItemBadge(index);
    });
}
```

**MainView.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MessagingCenter.Send<object, int>(this, "Add", 2);
}
```

As in my code above I tried with `UILabel`. However I cannot set `CornerRadius` for `Label`

**Summarize how I can Add Text inside Frame. Or how can I set CornerRadius for Lable in Xamarin iOS.**

Thank you!

Description picture:

[image]

If I use UILabel, I cannot set CornerRadius

[image]

If I use UIView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UILabel, you could set the **CornerRadius** using the following:

```
badgeView.Layer.CornerRadius = 7;
badgeView.Layer.MasksToBounds = true;//add this line
```

For more info, you could refer to [masksToBounds](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410896-maskstobounds?language=objc).

Hope it works for you.